# Log out after user creation, session key gone. D8.6.2 with CiviCRM 5.6.1

Tags: drupal

we successfully managed to get D8.6.2 with CiviCRM up and running.

But when creating a new user by D8-Admin, the user is logged out with error page access denied. The user is created correctly but the session is killed.

Deactivating of Profiles in CiviCRM causes the known error:

> > Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
> >     with more details about what action you were performing when this
> >     occurred. We can't load the requested web page. This page requires
> >     cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this
> >     setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again.
> >     If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.
>
> Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing
>   this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL.
>   EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing
>   the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like
>   http://myotherexample.org.
>
> Error type: Could not find a valid session key.

When checking the cookies during the user creation process, i see that the session cookies are gone after submitting of the creation form.

We tried to modify this part in civicrm.module:

> - Attach any relevant profile form fields to user registration form. 
>     */ function civicrm_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {   $civicrm = \Drupal::service('civicrm');
>     $civicrm->initialize();   $html =
>     \CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getEditHTML(NULL, '', NULL, TRUE, TRUE, NULL,
>     FALSE, $civicrm->getCtype());
>
>   // Need to disable the page cache. 
>     \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
>
>   // We need the CiviCRM core Javascript.
>     CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()->addCoreResources();
>
>   $form['civicrm_profile_register'] = [
>     '#markup' => Markup::create($html),    '#cache' => [
>      'max-age' => 0,
>     ],   ];   $form['#validate'][] = '_civicrm_user_register_form_validate'; }

to:

/* \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();*/ to stop the cache from beeing killed, but that had no impact.

Does anyone has an idea, who we can keep the session alive or give us a hint, where the problem might be?

THX
Lars

Comment: Look at the https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31752/3106